# Xcode: "Build and run" without restarting iPhone emulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, emulation, ios

I just started fighting my way to Xcode and iPhone development, so this is probably a stupid question, but there is this strange behavior of Xcode that I can't seem to get behind.

When I change my code (.m, .h files) and press "Build and Run", the (already running) emulator seems to restart my app, but doesn't actually reflect my changes.

On the other hand, if I modify the UI (the .xib files), I do see the changes after "Build and Run".

The only way to test the code changes seems to be to manually exit the emulator and restart, which I grow tired of very quickly.

There must be something I'm missing. What is it?

Comment: Are you positive it's not reflecting your changes?  I have never seen this behaviour before.  Does XCode ask you to "Stop Executable" before it starts up again?

Comment: Yes, it does. I press ok, after which the emulator shows the app closing and reappearing. Note that it doesn't seem to restart, or at least maintains state. For example, when using a FlipsideView, it'll show the side previously on top (the same behavior when pressing HOME and restarting the app within the emulator). I'm working with the iOS 4 SDK - is this related to multitasking maybe?

Comment: I am experiencing the same type of problem. If I start a new project and I add a UISegmentedcontrol on the View and I want to see how it looks in the simulator. The simulator only shows a grey screen as if I never did any change to it... 

So it refuses to show me my changes... I am usin VirtualBox with osx 10.6

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's this problem I'm running into:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2010/Jul/msg00026.html

No good solution in sight, though.